# Fragment creates an Activity object but it is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my fragment class, I create an object of my `Activity` class:

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
```

and in my fragment's `OnCreateView()`, I initialize it:

```
mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

However, when I debug my app, `mainActivity` is always null. Why is this?

My Activity class:

```
package com.example.brettrosen.atls;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
public ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Pre-arrival Plan", "Primary Survey", "Secondary Survey"};

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    updateTabTitles(0, 12);
    updateTabTitles(1, 2);
    updateTabTitles(2, 14);
}

public void updateTabTitles(int pageNum, int remaining) {
    String text = tabs[pageNum] + " (" + remaining + ")";
    System.out.println(actionBar);

    actionBar.getTabAt(pageNum).setText(text);
}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}


};
```

Comment: Have to add more code

Comment: Your fragment, where you are having the problem (not your Activity)

Comment: @Booger Thanks for the reply. `mainActivity = new MainActivity()` is in my `OnCreateView()` in my Fragment, when I put a breakpoint on that line it shows that mainActivity is null.

Comment: That's normal, it should stop being null at the next line. But you must never create an Activity yourself anyway, the system does it.

Comment: What exactly are you aiming to do with this code? Are you trying to start `MainActivity` from your fragment?

Comment: @ridsatrio Exactly, because I want to call a function in my MainActivity, but the problem is that whenever I do, the properties are null (I posted a question about this before this one)

Comment: @BladeCoder Thanks Blade, you're right it's not null afterwards however all of it's properties are null and this is what's causing my problem. I wonder why this is?

Comment: I see.. Is your `MainActivity` the one that hosts this fragment? Because you can't just create an Activity that way.

Comment: @ridsatrio Yes it is

Comment: @Brejuro No offense but you should read more documentation and tutorials first.

Comment: @BladeCoder On what? That doesn't really help

Comment: I'll try to be more helpful: Activities contain fragments, so it makes no sense that your Fragment creates a new Activity, it should be the other way around. Furthermore, it's the system that creates and initializes the Activities, and you can ask it to launch a new one by creating an Intent and calling startActivity(intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem is that you want to access `MainActivity` from within a fragment that it hosts.

To do that, you could just call this:

```
getActivity();
```

And it will return your `MainAcitvity` (or any other Activity that is currently hosting your Fragment).

To access a method from it, you'd have to cast the return of that method.

```
MainActivity yourMain = (MainActivity) getActivity();

yourMain.method1();
```

Remember to do this inside of your fragment.

Comment: How would I access a method from my activity using this?

Comment: Cast it to mainactivity

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was my problem for the last 2 hours or so!